# How do I add two quaternions in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

How do I add two quaternion variables together in C#? I'm working on a camera follow script, and I can't figure it out.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? there is likely a better way to do it, I don't think you can really add two quaternion variables

Answer (score 10, accepted):

a simple google search would have done it :)

```
QuaResult = Quaternion1 * Quaternion2;
```

You multiply instead of adding.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html?_ga=2.189207083.1638368031.1589073817-2131723030.1586048148