# Is there a method like subVectors() but for Quaternions?

Tags: three.js

I used to use getWorldRotation() with my Vector3 but since getWorldRotation() seems to be gone I am trying to use getWorldQuaternion(). But now I have another problem since before I used subVectors() and now can't do that if I'm having to switch to Quaternions. Is there any built in method like subVectors() for Quaternions?

Looked at Threejs docs for a bit but could't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getWorldRotation() got you the Euler angles, didn't it?
This will get you the Euler angles (I hope):

```
let quaternion, rotation;
object3d.getWorldQuaternion(quaternion);
rotation = new THREE.Euler().setFromQuaternion( quaternion, eulerOrder );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine the effect of two quaternion rotations, you multiply them, not add them. Similarly, If you want to subtract multiply it with its inverse.
[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61706086/6809917)

```
quatResult = new THREE.Quaternion().multiplyQuaternions(quaternion1, quaternion2.invert())
```